# What's the difference about vs2010 generation operation&copy to output directory?

Tags: c#

In visual studio 2010 ,the app.config(for example) attribute have two choice(or more):

- copy to output directory
- no copy
- copy
- if update then copy

what's the difference?

I have make help from MSDN,but i still don't understand.Because it just explain **the words meaning**! And not hit the point.

Why i ask because I have a problem with visual studio 2010 windows service(also test with windows form application):

When i set the app.config:

`no copy(copy to output directory)&&None(generate operation)`

the

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStr"].ConnectionString
```

can get the "connStr".

if i set the app.config:

```
copy(copy to output directory)&&embeded resource(generate operation)
```

the

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connStr"].ConnectionString
```

generate an error:

```
not set the object referece of the object
```

How to expain the situation?More detail ,More better.

Comment: App.config is special, it needs to be *renamed* to YourApp.exe.config and copied to the build directory before it can work.  The build system already knows how to do this, don't help.  "Do not copy" is the correct setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate applies config transforms depending on your compile target for Web.config files...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

...but I'm not sure if it works for non-Web.config files.